# How to creat realm db from string-array & load this in my activity?

Tags: java, android, database, realm

I have a problem, I want to write database with realm. My data is String, and their number is more than 500, and I wrote them as a String, and I would like to save all data by the realm during the first program run.
Is there a way that I do not enter all the information individually?
What is your suggestion?
tnx

Comment: provide more details.

Comment: My data includes 500 names and 500 phone numbers. I wrote this data in string.xml.
My data is 2 String-Array.
I would like Realm read this String-Array and show it in the log so that the first Id one belongs to the first name and telephone number in String-Array.

Comment: check my Answer.

Answer (score 0):

- Create JSON file with data instead write in string.xml.

And **copy json file to assets**.

- Make Model class.
- Your JSON look like ,

```json
[
  {
    "Name": "Michael",
    "Phone": 2525055
  },
  {
    "Name": "Anthony",
    "Phone": 665588
  },
  {
    "Name": "Dana",
    "Phone": 245244
  }
]
```

**Model class**

```
public class People extends RealmObject {
    private String Name;
    private int Phone;

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public int getPhone() {
        return Phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(int Phone) {
        this.Phone = Phone;
    }
}
```

**Then Import data using Realm**

```
public class RealmImporter {

        // From json to realm database

    static void importFromJson(final Resources resources) {
            Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            //transaction timer
        final TransactionTime transactionTime = new TransactionTime(System.currentTimeMillis());

        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                InputStream inputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.people);
                try {
                    realm.createAllFromJson(People.class, inputStream);
                    transactionTime.setEnd(System.currentTimeMillis());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    realm.close();
                }
            }
        });
        Log.d("Realm", "createAllFromJson Task completed in " + transactionTime.getDuration() + "ms");
    }
}
```

**Update**

You can get data using findAll Like,

```
RealmResults<Person> details = realm.where(Person.class).equalTo("Name","Anthony").findAll();
```

Comment: Instead of "InputStream inputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.people);", I have to use "InputStream inputStream = resources.getAssets().open("myjson.json");", right? and how can I show Anthony's number in textview in main activity?

Comment: Yes, you can import json from assets.